# Gcloud::Datastore::ApiError - Api call runQuery is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

When i run on local. Everything is going okay.

But my appication is not running on cloud provide url

```
https://<your-project-id>.appspot.com
```

But working Great on locally.

When first time i deploy its work for me `https://<your-project-id>.appspot.com` but when i add class and apply add, delete, edit operation its not work on `https://<your-project-id>.appspot.com` but still working on local.

After deploy

```
    "response": {
    "betaSettings": {
        "has_docker_image": "True"
    }, 
    "name": "apps/trial-project-1103/modules/default/versions/20151021t211200", 
    "handlers": [
        {
            "securityLevel": "SECURE_NEVER", 
            "authFailAction": "AUTH_FAIL_ACTION_REDIRECT", 
            "urlRegex": ".*", 
            "login": "LOGIN_OPTIONAL", 
            "script": {
                "scriptPath": "PLACEHOLDER"
            }
        }
    ], 
    "manualScaling": {
        "instances": 1
    }, 
    "vm": true, 
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1beta4.Version", 
    "runtime": "custom", 
    "id": "20151021t211200", 
    "resources": {
        "diskGb": 10, 
        "cpu": 0.5, 
        "memoryGb": 1.2999999523162842
    }, 
    "threadsafe": true
}, 
"done": true, 
"name": "apps/trial-project-1103/operations/e302b28c-6984-4362-a823-891f8806e10d", 
"metadata": {
    "target": "apps/trial-project-1103/modules/default/versions/20151021t211200", 
    "insertTime": "2015-10-21T16:14:55.935Z", 
    "method": "google.appengine.v1beta4.Versions.CreateVersion", 
    "user": "sajjadmurtaza.nxb@gmail.com", 
    "operationType": "create_version", 
    "endTime": "2015-10-21T16:17:44.649Z", 
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1beta4.OperationMetadata"
}
```

}

Please guide me why this is happening.?

[image: API call to runQuery was not successful]

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to answer your first question without knowing a lot more about your app.

To answer your second, logs are found in the Google Cloud Platform [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com). Select your project, then navigate to **Monitoring > Logs**. You'll be able to see all of the logs for your project.

Comment: I saw but i have no idea why this is

Comment: 19:13:30.115
0
0 B
3,310.74 s
/_ah/background
0.1.0.3 - - [21/Oct/2015:07:13:30 -0700] "GET /_ah/background HTTP/1.1" - - - "-" "0.20151021t190959.trial-project-1103.appspot.com" ms=3310742 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0 instance=- app_engine_release=- trace_id=-

Comment: can you help me about that.?

Comment: Can you find and post a complete Ruby backtrace (stacktrace)? It should point to line numbers in Ruby files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you successfully followed this tutorial?

https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/hello-world

Comment: yes this is done successfully. but when i added class and ruby class the deployed its not working. But locally working good.

Comment: 19:13:30.115 0 0 B 3,310.74 s /_ah/background 0.1.0.3 - - [21/Oct/2015:07:13:30 -0700] "GET /_ah/background HTTP/1.1" - - - "-" "0.20151021t190959.trial-project-1103.appspot.com" ms=3310742 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0 instance=- app_engine_release=- trace_id=- –

Comment: That log entry is not helpful. Please post more of the logs. There should be a entry for the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." response with a 500 status code.

Comment: I don't know where is the problem

Comment: Gcloud::Datastore::ApiError in BookMarksController#index
API call to runQuery was not successful

Answer (score 0):

if you can't ssh into the machine & see the production.log. then, you can enable logging by adding the following to `config/environments/production.rb` & deploy again

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
```

This will show the error in the browser itself

Comment: API call to runQuery was not successfu

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you've enabled **Datastore API** in the Developer Console. Also, double check your **Project ID** and your **Dataset ID** (which should be the same as the project ID).

In my experience, these are the most common reasons for this error.